# log4j debug message configuration

Tags: logging, log4j, append

I am able to use my Logger with the simple call:

```
logger.debug("blablablalbal");
```

It is also configured by an xml file and writes into a txt.

Problem is: 
Sometimes i am looping over int values in a large array and therefore the output becomes extremely long in terms of lines used.
For Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < largeArray.length; i++){
    logger.debug(largeArray[i])
}
```

I know that i could use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < largeArray.length; i++){
    System.out.print(largeArray[i])
}
```

But i want to have everything together and utilize the logger for this task. Does someone know how to "imitate" System.out.print() with log4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Arrays.toString()` (Java 5 or above)

```
logger.debug(Arrays.toString(largeArray));
for(int i = 0; i < largeArray.length; i++){
    ...
}
```